# Using a C++ Class in Visual Studio - undeclared identifier error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I expect this is incredibly simple but can't for the life of me figure out whats wrong. I'm new to C++ and I've created a C++ class in visual studio and am trying to use it in the main method of another file. I've stripped everything back to the bare minimum but still I can't get it to run. The first compile error I get is 'Test': undeclared identifier. If I remove 'Test test;' from App.cpp it all compiles fine.
Below is the code. Can anybody help?

App.cpp:

```
#include "Test.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Test test;
    //cout << test.getNumber() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Test.h:

```
#pragma once
class Test
{
private:
    int number;

public:
    int getNumber();
    Test();
    ~Test();
};
```

Test.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test.h"


int Test::getNumber()
{
    return number;
}

Test::Test()
{
    this->number = 1;
}


Test::~Test()
{
}
```

Comment: Place this include  #include "Test.h" after this #include "stdafx.h"

Comment: Visual studio does not compile anything before `#include "stdafx.h"`, if using precompiled headers.

Comment: The problem is that VS defaults to using the "precompiled headers" feature of Visual C++, which makes the preprocessor behave in decidedly non-standard ways. One fix is as @VladfromMoscow notes, to let the precompiled header (here `"stdafx.h"`) be the first include in every implementation file. A better solution is to just **turn off precompiled headers** in the project settings. Right-click project → Properties → turn it off. There.

Comment: Really? That was it... Well I did say it must be simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `"stdafx.h"` is pre-compiled.
Visual c++ will not compile anything before the `#include "stdafx.h"` in the source file, unless the compile option `/Yu'stdafx.h'` is unchecked (by default); it assumes all code in the source up to and including that line is already compiled.

The solution is to move it to be the first `include`.

You can read more about it in the wiki page of [Precompiled header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header).